# Margin or Padding CSS to Add Space between Two Objects

Tags: css, joomla

Good Afternoon Everyone,

Ok so Im using Joomla and I've added some Custom Text to a Component. The Top of the Test has a Margin which seems to work in adding some space, the Bottom of text also has Margin BUT no space is added between it and the next object.

Custom Class for the Custom Text

```
#albumstats {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Link To Page ---> http://macthedj.com/mixtapes/K/2-kodak-black/8-lil-b-i-g-pac.html

If anyone can provide an explanation on how to achieve this goal of adding space at the bottom of the Text, that would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: In my opinion, this question should be easy to fix if you read up on CSS.

Comment: I'm not sure what happens, what you want to happen, and what you tried. Also a good idea to provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `float: left;` on `#albumstats`, like:

```
#albumstats {
  float: left;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Float Worked! Thanks!

Im not exactly sure how this elements works, but im going to do some more research to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `<div class="clearfix"></div>` at end of `#albumstats`, Because this children has `float: left`, *elements that have `float` don't detect by their parent*

```
<div id="albumstats">
    <!-- your code -->
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

After add this, the `margin` and `padding` will be apply